# Handling hierarchical category independent variables

Tags: classification, pandas, hierarchical-data-format, dummy-variables

I have data with huge categorical attributes.

For example, main_column, sub_column1, sub_column2 are 3 hierarchical attributes. 
If if take dummy variable on these columns the column count is increased to 1000.

How to handle this kind of hierarchical attributes for a classification problem ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

- 3 features, one for each level `main_column`, `sub_column1`, `sub_column2`
- 2 additional features representing the hierarchical relation:

  - `main_column/sub_column1`
  - `main_column/sub_column1/sub_column2`

This way the training can select the most informative level of information between `main_column`, `main_column/sub_column1`, `main_column/sub_column1/sub_column2`. Depending on the data and algorithm used it might also make sense to discard rare cases for a subcategory and use a kind of "misc" category instead.